# How do I specify the height and width of a external swf? AS3

Tags: flash, height, width, external, loading

I want to load an external swf file into my project. My project is much smaller than the project I am loading in and I need to make the external swf file smaller to fit. Whenever I added the myLoader.width and myLoader.height the project cannot be seen. If I take it away the myLoader.width and myLoader, the project will load fine but it is too big.

here is my code,

```
stop();
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickButton2);
calm_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickButton2);
linden_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickButton2);
moving_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickButton2);

var myLoader:Loader=new Loader();

var xPos:Number = 45;

var yPos:Number = 85;

function ClickButton2(Event:MouseEvent):void

{

if(Event.target==home_btn)

{
    gotoAndStop("home");
}

else if(Event.target==calm_btn)
{
    gotoAndStop("calm");
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Project 2 Scott Parker FINAL.swf");
    myLoader.load(myURL);
    myLoader.x = xPos;
    myLoader.y = yPos;
    myLoader.width = 100;
    myLoader.height = 100;
    addChild(myLoader);
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you want myLoader.content.width = 100;

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html

*edit

```
function ClickButton2(event:MouseEvent):void

{

if(event.target==home_btn)

{
    gotoAndStop("home");
}

else if(event.target==calm_btn)
{
    gotoAndStop("calm");
    var myURL:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Project 2 Scott Parker FINAL.swf");
    myLoader.load(myURL);
    myLoader.x = xPos;
    myLoader.y = yPos;

    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(){
        myLoader.content.width = 100;
        myLoader.content.height= 100;
    });

    addChild(myLoader);
}
```

Comment: You will get this error when trying to resize it when it hasnt loaded yet. Try the code snippet in my updated answer instead...

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code snippet to include more of your code so you can see where it goes.

Comment: I copied and pasted what you put into my code and I get this error:1119: Access of possibly undefined property COMPLETE through a reference with static type flash.events:MouseEvent.

Comment: That is because your ClickButton2 has a parameter called Event. This should be renamed to be lowercase so it doesn't clash with the Event package name. I will update my code example